# Problem with PHP PDO ODBC extension when upgrading PHP 5.6 to 7.1

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, ignite, unixodbc

We have a setup with PHP 5.6. We are using Apache Ignite datagrid for caching purposes. We are using PDO(pdo_odbc) over unixODBC to execute sql queries on the ignite cache. The code is as below,

`$res = $this->connection()->query($selectQuery)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`

Here, the `connection()` function returns a PDO object. The SQL is of the following format,

`SELECT stu.name FROM "StudentCache".Student AS stu WHERE stu.is_qualified = \'1\'  ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0`

The code is working fine on PHP 5.6 deployment. The code returns an array of the column values. By default, the `FETCH_COLUMN` returns the first column(only one in our case).

**Problem**

Now the problem is that when I upgraded php to 7.1, the same piece of code is throwing a pdo exception. Below is the exact error,

`SQLSTATE[SL009]: <<Unknown error>>: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]No columns were bound prior to calling SQLFetch or SQLFetchScroll (SQLFetchScroll[0] at /home/buildozer/aports/community/php7/src/php-7.1.17/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:559)`

But if the column name is replaced with `*`, there is no error. The entire result set is returned as an array. However, for our use-case, we want to be able to specify the column as parsing the result set is unnecessary overhead.

I've searched for similar issues with out much success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please ask if you need any more details.

Comment: `"StudentCache".Student` should probably be `\`StudentCache\`.Student`. Quotes don't treat values as table names/columns, backticks do.

Comment: Another note is you can replace `fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` with `fetch()` to get the same result set. I would also capitalize all non-variable words in your query (Not required, but easier to read) `SELECT stu.name FROM StudentCache.Student AS stu WHERE stu.is_qualified='1' ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. But the format of the above SQL is required by Apache Ignite. Back ticks do not work in ignite.

Comment: Gotcha. Well just take out the quotes/backticks completely. The table name you use there is not a reserved name, so it shouldn't be necessary anyways.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The `StudentCache` is the cache name. It is necessary in Ignite to surround the cache name with double quotes. In any case, I'll try other formats. But I don't suspect that is the issue here. As I've mentioned, the same piece of code was working fine previously.

Comment: Also, `fetch` would only return one row. I will have to loop over the statement. Where as, `fetchAll` would return the entire result set at once. I didn't quite understand how it would return the same result set without having to loop over it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180673/discussion-between-i-v-harish-and-grumpycrouton).

Comment: You're right about `fetch()`, I'm not sure why I thought that. I'm not familiar with ODBC, so I'm probably not going to be much more help.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does this link perhaps help: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?347149-ODBC-error-No-columns-were-bound-prior-to-calling-SQLFetchScroll

Comment: @alamar Thanks for this. I came across this as well, not of much use for me.